# Does "のほうが" necessarily imply a comparison?

Tags: meaning, usage

If you were to translate a phrase like "東京のほうが寒いです" without any knowledge of the context it is being used on, would the most accurate translation still be "Tokyo is colder (than someplace else)"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A comparison is implicit within the phrase ～の方が～です。If someone were to say this without context, the listener would be left wondering 'compared to where?'.

> AよりBの方がいいです。'A is better than B.'
>
> Bの方がいい。'B is better'... Must have pre-established context to make sense.
>
> Bの方が、Aより全然いい。'B is better, way better than A.'